Creating a filesystem with 'semi' public URLs, to be used in templates
I have created a 'dashboard' for my clients with Twig templates and user groups with different permissions.
I have multiple users which can add images, which get uploaded to a file system created for this purpose.
Right now this file system has public URLs, however I would want them only visible to (logged in) users, using the dashboard.
Is there a way to generate a special URL for these assets, or use permissions to allow users to view these images? Instead of each asset having a public URL which can be seen by anyone having the URL?
Thank you!
